# Change refresh rate of laptop LCD

Tags: macbook-pro, display

How can I change the refresh rate of a 2014 retina MacBook Pro? System Preferences doesn't have this option, so I guess it must be buried in a plist somewhere. I want to use 72hz for video playback because its a multiple of 24.

Comment: Though it's a reasonable request, we don't know why you want a multiple of 24Hz.  I can guess - you might be pointing a camera at it.  Or connected a monitor or projector and want to improve the appearance.  Or something else?  If you can tell us why, it might be easier to find a solution.

Comment: I want to watch video files at 24fps, to see the true motion without interpolation.